# Windows (.lnk) shortcuts API?

Tags: c++, windows, shortcut

Are there any functions that allow you to create shortcuts in Windows just like you can create symlinks in Linux? I'd preferably like to be able to edit things like the target and name instead of having to re-create a whole new shortcut every time I want to change something due to an update.

I tried opening a `.lnk` file in a text editor and it was a whole bunch of gobbelty gook. I wonder why it's half binary as shortcuts on Linux are like an `.ini` file, simple and easy to use. I am afraid that if I go romping though the data, I might upset some sort of checksum and the shortcut won't work so that is why I am wondering if there is a specific API that should be called to tinker with these objects.

Update: I have found a function to query shortcut data `MsiGetShortcutTarget()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370299(v=vs.85).aspx , but nothing yet on creating or modifying shortcuts.

Comment: `MsiGetShortcutTarget()` is for Windows Installer link files, not general link files. The doc you link to even says to use `IShellLink` for files that `MsiGetShortcutTarget()` fails to load.

Comment: In Windows, Shell links (or shortcuts) and symlinks are two different things.  To create a symlink, use CreateSymbolicLink().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969393.aspx) for MSDN documentation on shell links.

Comment: That seems annoying for creating shortcuts... I guess everything is like that though.

Comment: Most things in the Windows Shell are accessed via COM objects.